# best way to install ROS in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, installation, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to install ROS Melodic in Ubuntu 18.04. I've already read the [installation guide](https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) but also I just found out that there is a ROS package directly in the repositories of Ubuntu, so if I run: `apt search ros-desktop` it appears to be some available packages, `ros-desktop-full` included, which from the installation guide looks very similar to `ros-melodic-desktop-full` which is the suggested package.

The only difference that I see  in the installation process is that with the installation guide I would setup the **sources.list** file to accept software from *packages.ros.org* and setup the keys with `apt-key`

So is there any difference between those two packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327724/best-way-to-install-ros-in-ubuntu-18.04/) by [Cardoso1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/43955/cardoso1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I honestly don't know where the ros packages in the ubuntu universe repo come from, but they are definitely not what you want. If you look at the [changelog of any of those packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ros-desktop-full), you see that there has not been much going on.

You should definitely follow the installation guide on the ROS wiki!

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-05**:
The packages the OP mentions are [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

I would strongly recommend OP installs the regular packages, not the upstream ones.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-07-08**:
@gvdhoorn thanks for the clarification, didn't know this! I agree with using the regular packages.

**Comment by [Cardoso1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/43955/cardoso1994/) on 2019-07-11**:
Thanks for the help. I installed melodic the ROS way.